# Selenium grid accept request and wait for all the nodes to come up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a `selenium grid hub` connected to 20 `nodes`. I usually shut down all the `nodes` when they are not used. So before I start a test I spin up all the `nodes` and hard wait for 60 seconds for the `nodes` to come up. But unfortunately it takes longer than 60 seconds and I need the requests to sit in the `Hub` until all nodes come up. How can I achieve that? Can I at least specify how long the requests can sit on the hub before it timesout?

This is how I start the `hub`

```
java -jar ~/automation/tools/selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub -port 8007 -maxSession 1 -newSessionWaitTimeout 600000 -timeout 50 -log /var/log/grid.log
```

I get the following exception right after 60 seconds if the nodes are not available for execution.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new
>   session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities
>   [{chrome.switches=[--no-default-browser-check], nativeEvents=false,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, goog:chromeOptions={args=[test-type,
>   allow-running-insecure-content], extensions=[],
>   prefs={profile.password_manager_enabled=false,
>   download.default_directory=C:/downloads/}},
>   unhandledPromptBehavior=accept, browserName=chrome, video=True,
>   chrome.prefs={profile.password_manager_enabled=false,
>   download.default_directory=C:/downloads/}, platformName=ANY, version=,
>   platform=ANY, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}] 10:58:20 Command
>   duration or timeout: 55 milliseconds

Comment: I am not sure if there is an option that exists for this. But if you find nothing then it is possible to put a nginx using upstream and failover handling using same server probably

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Do you have an example?

Comment: Not right away. But you can have look at https://superuser.com/questions/746028/configuring-nginx-to-retry-a-single-upstream-server and https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-configure-nginx-to-hold-the-connections-and-retry-if-the-proxied-server-returns-502-cilngkof700iteq53ratetsry. If they don't help you then let me know

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Is it possible to provide a snippet that will help me achieve this pls?